# Wordpress page not taking precedence over server directory

Tags: wordpress, redirect, server

On my wordpress site, I have a page mysite.com/download. On the same server I have a directory named download, where I store files which I need to provide on download page. So the problem is that when someone tries to access mysite.com/download, he's taken to the directory instead of the page. I have turned off the directory access for now, so it currently displays no permission to access. I want wordpress to display the page instead of the directory. I am not sure if it's a problem with the server or wordpress. I hope someone can clarify.

Comment: Have you already created the page in wordpress with the desired url slug, and toggled your permalinks since changing your server settings?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a redirection rule to your download.php file like this using `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/download.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$
RewriteRule .* /download.php [L,R=302]
```